# IF test combining 2 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I am a casual user of Excel supporting my daughters ETSY business . Periodically I have to modify formulas and after trying several options require assistance.

I am stuck with what I think should be simple but have tried several things This is a formula that works but I need to combine a test with it to see if contents of cell B has the word "Tax" in it. If it does I need to enter a value of 0.

```vb
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4)),0)
```

Comment: You can nest IF function. `=if(B2='Tax',0,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4)),0)`. Just adjust if you need to search for Tax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response and suggestion.

Comment: I apologize for my poor description -- The condition should be --- if B2='Tax' and c2 does have the word Processing then set cell to 0. otherwise it enters value of G2  I hope this makes sense

Comment: @Isolated I believe your comment is missing a right parenthesis at the end to close out the newly added IF.

Comment: @JackElliott I think you are trying to get here then:  `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),B2="Tax"),0,VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4)))`  I am confused thought, in your question example, you have the true value being the extract of G4, and the false value being 0,  In your comment, you describe 0 being the "if true" value.  The formula I just entered applies "0 if true".

Comment: Once again I thank you very much for responding and apologize for my confusing description. When I enter =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),B2='Tax'),0,VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4))) it gives me that error message when it does not like something. The current formula I have is =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4)),0)   and that works if "Processing" is found in C2 it enters the value of G2 else it enters 0 -- I want to test b2 to see if it contains 'Tax" -- if it does it enters 0 even if C2 has "Processing"

Comment: @JackElliott Importantly…  Do you want to test if the cells are specifically “Processing” and “Tax”, or are you trying to test if the text then those cells *includes* “Processing” and “Tax” mixed amongst other words that might be in the same cell?  The word “contains” has a specific connotation in database contexts.  A cell whose value is `Sales Tax` *contains* “Tax” but dies not equal “Tax”.

Comment: Thanks for staying with me Max!! The formula =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Processing",C2)),VALUE(RIGHT(G2,4)),0) worked before because the B2 cell was always "Fee" but the new download now has added "Tax" in B2 and I want the cell to load 0 if B2 = Tax and follow the formula if B2="Fee" ---- so my thought was to only test for B2="tax"

Comment: It’s easier to implement, and follow, if you test for two true or two false conditions.  So “when Processing AND Fee are both true, then follow formula, in all other cases = 0”.  Is that the correct logic?

Comment: Yes that would work.